# How to remove radio button selected off

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

[Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/rnnb32rm/1845/)

Here I have a table, In this add button is there, each time radio button will be added,
When I click on clear button then the selected radio button should be unselected.

```
$scope.Clear = function() {
  radiobtn = document.getElementById("theid");
  radiobtn.checked = false;  
};
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several issues with your code

- You are missing `ng-click` in your `clear` button which should have `ng-click="Clear()"`
- You cannot have `ng-id = "theid"` as the radio buttons are dynamically created and it is not a good practice to have same `id` value for multiple elements
- You can then use `JQuery` to reset the marked radio buttons in that group but when you use `ng-model` to get the value of the radio buttons i would suggest to use `ng-model` to reset the radio button values.

```js
var app = angular.module('angularjs-starter', []);

  app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  
  $scope.names = ['Mobile','Office','Home'];

  $scope.choices = [{id: 'choice1'}];
  
  $scope.addNewChoice = function() {
    var newItemNo = $scope.choices.length+1;
    $scope.choices.push({'id':'choice'+newItemNo});
  };
  
  
  $scope.Clear = function() {
    $('input[type="radio"]').attr('checked', false);
  };  
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="angularjs-starter" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
   <fieldset ng-model='y' ng-repeat="choice in choices">
      <select>
         <option ng-model='x1' ng-repeat = "x in names">{{x}}</option>
      </select>
      <input value="aa" type="radio" name="na"/>
   </fieldset>
   <button class="addfields" ng-click="addNewChoice()">Add fields</button>
    <button class="addfields" ng-click="Clear()">Clear</button>
</div>
```

Comment: The "correct" way is `$(el).prop("checked",false);` since `checked` is a boolean **property**. The attribute should only be used to pass the property on load.  +1 anyway because the rest is good and well explained ;)

Comment: By the way... OP was ok with the Angular way to change the radio property. See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Bes7weB/sy0xdz75/) where there is no jQuery use.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette three things here. OP has not specified `angular way`, OP has tagged question with `javascript` and `jquey` and OP has himself used `javascript` in his code snippet.

Comment: Okay... Don't take it as a blame.. I'm just commenting to add some more. Your answer is correct. I upvoted. What's the problem?

Comment: Relax mate. @LouysPatriceBessette No problem at all. I also commented to make more clear. I appreciate your comment and upvote.